# TailwindCSS Dynamic classes aren't comiled in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I was passing color name through props in custom react component.
And using it like this.

```
<div className={`bg-${color}-100 mx-auto p-5 inline-block rounded-full`}>
  <div className={`border-4 p-3 border-${color}-800 rounded-full`}>
    <Icon name={icon} className={`text-6xl text-${color}-800`} />
  </div>
</div>
```

The colors are extend in `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary': {
          '50': '#f0f9ff',
          '100': '#e0f2fe',
          '200': '#bbe6fc',
          '300': '#7ed3fb',
          '400': '#3abcf6',
          '500': '#10a4e7',
          '600': '#0485c7',
          '700': '#05699f',
          '800': '#085984',
          '900': '#0d4a6d',
          '950': '#092f48',
        },
        // Other colors...
      },
    },
  },
  safelist: [
    'bg-primary-100',
    'bg-secondary-100',
    'bg-success-100',
    'bg-warning-100',
    'bg-danger-100',
    'text-danger-800',
    'border-danger-800'
  ],
  plugins: [],
};
```

I temporarily fixed the problem by using `safelist`. But I need more classes and I can't add them mannually in `safelist`.

I want to pass colors through props and want them to be compiled by tailwindcss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using a dictionary like:

```
const COLORS = {
  primary: {
    bg: 'bg-primary-100',
    border: 'border-primary-800',
    text: 'text-primary-800',
  },
  // …
};
// …
<div className={`${COLORS[color].bg} mx-auto p-5 inline-block rounded-full`}>
  <div className={`border-4 p-3 ${COLORS[color].border} rounded-full`}>
    <Icon name={icon} className={`text-6xl ${COLORS[color].text}`} />
```